How to implement Google reCAPTCHA Enterprise in a .NET MAUI Android app?
I've been trying to implement reCAPTCHA Enterprise on a .NET MAUI Android app. But I can't seem to convert get the IRecaptchaTasksClient object. Casting the OnSuccess result object leads to an invalid cast. I am using the Xamarin.Google.Android.Recaptcha binding library from Microsoft.
Xamarin
   .Google
   .Android
   .Recaptcha
   .Recaptcha
   .GetTasksClient(Application, AppId)
       .AddOnSuccessListener(new RecaptchaSuccessListener());

internal class RecaptchaSuccessListener : Java.Lang.Object, Android.Gms.Tasks.IOnSuccessListener
{
    public void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result)
    {
        var test = (Xamarin.Google.Android.Recaptcha.IRecaptchaClient)result;
    }
}


You can try to use JavaCast in your code to get the IRecaptchaClient：
var test = result.JavaCast<IRecaptchaClient>();

For more details about JavaCast, you can refer to Extensions.JavaCast(IJavaObject) Method.

Simply put, you can try to replace the (Xamarin.Google.Android.Recaptcha.IRecaptchaClient)result in the code with result.JavaCast<IRecaptchaClient>().
